# MYSQL Update doesn't work consistently

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, html, mysqli

I have included in my back end a table that populates a list of courses. When an admin clicks edit course, he is able to edit them, and upon clicking update the variables are updated in the mysql database.

The problem is that the update does seem to work with all courses, where the courses information are nearly identical. it seems to only work half of the time. I was wondering if there was a work around the following:

```
<?php

//getting the text data from the fields
    if(isset($_POST['update_course'])) {
        $update_id          =   $pro_id;
        $course_provider    =   $_POST['course_provider'];
        $course_price       =   $_POST['course_price'];
        $course_desc        =   $_POST['course_desc'];
        $course_sdesc       =   $_POST['course_sdesc'];
        $course_editor      =   $_POST['course_editor'];
        $course_prereq      =   $_POST['course_prereq'];
        $course_tax         =   $_POST['course_tax'];

        $update_course      =   "update courses set course_updated='<b>$course_editor</b>', course_priceFinal=$course_tax*$course_price, course_tax='$course_tax', course_prereq='$course_prereq', course_sdesc='$course_sdesc'
        where course_id2 ='$update_id'";
        $run_course = mysqli_query($con, $update_course);

        if($run_course) {
            echo "<script>window.open('index.php?view_course','_self')</script>";
        }
        else {
            echo "<script>window.open('index.php?view_course','_self')</script>";
        }
    } ?>
```

I a greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: hows you getting the `$pro_id` ?

Comment: this is how 
$row_pro=mysqli_fetch_array($run_pro);
 $pro_id = $row_pro['course_id2'];
 thanks

Comment: You shouldn't be just processing raw POST data, that's a security issue. Also, you're not making sure these values are not blank or NULL, so that could potentially be a problem too.

Comment: What is your structure for price? Are you using float? Is your database set up for it? How many decimal places does it accept? Is the input field limiting those values? Are you just truncating extra digits?

Answer (score -1):

Try changing your statement to:

```
$update_course = update courses set course_updated='".$course_editor."',
course_priceFinal='".$course_tax*$course_price."', 
course_tax='".$course_tax."', course_prereq='".$course_prereq."', 
course_sdesc='".$course_sdesc."' where course_id2 ='".$update_id."'
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, wouldn't i need to put the quotation around update courses like "update courses....."

Comment: Yes.. you can put it...                                                                               $update_course = "update courses set course_updated='".$course_editor."',
course_priceFinal='".$course_tax*$course_price."', 
course_tax='".$course_tax."', course_prereq='".$course_prereq."', 
course_sdesc='".$course_sdesc."' where course_id2 ='".$update_id."'"